# How to make a button that wraps selected text in a div with a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nicedit

I am using nicedit in the textarea in the admin panel in my website. Now I want to add a custom button that will make the selected text wrap in a div with class=info .
I used the info in the nicedit wiki. and here is my js file code so far:

```
/**
* nicInfodiv
* @description: Adds blue square wrapper to text
* @requires: nicCore, nicPane, nicAdvancedButton
* @author: Brian Kirchoff
* @version: 0.9.0
*/

/* START CONFIG */
var nicInfodivOptions = {
    buttons : {
        'infodiv' : {name : __('Some alt text for the button'), type : 'nicEditorInfodiv'}
    }/* NICEDIT_REMOVE_START */,iconFiles : {'infodiv' : '/js/nicInfodiv/icons/div.gif'}/* NICEDIT_REMOVE_END */
};
/* END CONFIG */

var nicEditorInfodiv = nicEditorButton.extend({   
  mouseClick : function() {
   //WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE????
  }
});

nicEditors.registerPlugin(nicPlugin,nicInfodivOptions);
```

I can't find help anywhere. can anyone give me the appropriate code to write in the mouseclick event so that it will add the div class=info wrapper to the text selected?
can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

```
$(this).wrap('<div class="info"></div>');
```

This will create a new wrapper `div` around the element every time it is clicked. If you allow this to be clicked more than once, you would probably want to create the wrapper `div` once when the element is created, and then simply add the `info` class to the parent div later.

```
$(this).parent().addClass('info');
```

Comment: thanks, but I need to add the wrapper div to the selected  text, not to the button I clicked.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. You can access the DOM's selected text with `window.getSelection().toString()`. Then it's a matter of accessing this text with jQuery selector and using it instead of `this`.